# MILP problem is optimal when I comment out the first constraint but infeasible otherwise, python pulp. (UPDATED)

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, pulp, mixed-integer-programming

I have a MILP problem for re-configuring a 33-bus network in order to minimize the power losses defined by the following constraints:
[image: List of constraints for MILP problem]

The variables in the constraints are defined by  the following definitions:
[image: Nomenclature]

I also have the LPfile of the infeasible constraints in case that can be of [use](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hassantahan/tmu-ele-capstone/main/lpfiletest?token=GHSAT0AAAAAACB4BS6TDDF7HZLW44XDU6YGZCIPAMA)

I have the following code defining my constraints, I created the arrays from data I got from an IEEE file.

```
    ###############################################################################
    #                      START OF PROBLEM DECLARATION                           #
    ###############################################################################

    #Declare LParrays for storing LP variables
    PS_arr = []
    QS_arr = []
    PF_arr = []
    QF_arr = []
    W_arr = []
    slack_arr = []

    #define the minimization problem
    prob = pulp.LpProblem('Network-Reconfiguration', LpMinimize)

    #create generation second end power variables
    # PSG = LpVariable("PSG", cat='Continous')
    # QSG = LpVariable("QSG", cat='Continous')

    #generate the LP vars
    for i in range(len(FN)):

        W_arr.append(LpVariable("W{}_{}".format(FN[i],SN[i]),lowBound=0,upBound=1, cat='Binary'))

        PS_arr.append(LpVariable("PS{}_{}".format(FN[i],SN[i]), cat = 'Continous'))
        QS_arr.append(LpVariable("QS{}_{}".format(FN[i],SN[i]), cat = 'Continous'))

        PF_arr.append(LpVariable("PF{}_{}".format(FN[i],SN[i]), cat = 'Continous'))
        QF_arr.append(LpVariable("QF{}_{}".format(FN[i],SN[i]), cat = 'Continous'))

        slack_arr.append(LpVariable("slack{}_{}".format(FN[i],SN[i]), cat = 'Continous'))

    print(PS_arr)
    print(QS_arr)
    print(PF_arr)
    print(QF_arr)
    print(W_arr)
    print(FN)
    print(SN)

    # objective function
    prob += lpSum(-(PF + PS) for PF,PS in zip(PF_arr,PS_arr))


    for i in range(len(FN)):
        f = i
        s = i
        # constraint 1
        # prob += -10**6 * (1-W_L)<= 1 + 2*(PS_L*Z_L + QS_L*X_L - 0.5) + (PS_L**2 + QS_L**2) * Z_L**2 <= 10**6 * (1-W_L)
        prob += 1+2*(PS_arr[i]*R[i] + QS_arr[i]*X[i] - 0.5) + (PL[i] + QL[i]) * Z[i]**2 >= -10**6*(1 - W_arr[i])
        prob += 1+2*(PS_arr[i]*R[i] + QS_arr[i]*X[i] - 0.5) + (PL[i] + QL[i]) * Z[i]**2 <= 10**6*(1 - W_arr[i])

        # constraint 2
        # prob += PF_L + PS_L + R_L(PL_L + QL_L) == 0
        # prob += PL_L - PS_L >= 0
        # prob += PL_L - PF_L >= 0
        prob += PF_arr[f] + PS_arr[s] + R[i]*(PL[i]*W_arr[i]) == 0
        # prob += PF_arr[f] + PS_arr[s] + R[i]*W_arr[i] == 0
        print(f"{PF_arr[f]} + {PS_arr[s]} + {R[i]}")
        # prob += PL[i] >= PF_arr[f]
        # prob += PL[i] >= PS_arr[s]
        # print("Line "+str(i)+": "+str(PF_arr[i])+" + "+str(PS_arr[i])+" ... "+str(FN[i])+" to "+str(SN[i]))

        # constraint 3
        # prob += QF_L + QS_L + X_L * (PL_L + QL_L) == 0
        # prob += QL_L - QS_L >= 0
        # prob += QL_L - QF_L >= 0
        prob += QF_arr[f] + QS_arr[s] + X[i]*(QL[i]*W_arr[i]) == 0
        # prob += QF_arr[f] + QS_arr[s] + X[i]*W_arr[i] == 0
        # prob += QL[i] >= QS_arr[s]
        # prob += QL[i] >= QF_arr[f]

        # constraint 6
        # prob += -10^6 *W_L <= PS_L <= 10^6*W_L
        prob += PS_arr[s] >= -10**6*W_arr[s]
        prob += PS_arr[s] <= 10**6*W_arr[s]

        #constraint 7
        #prob += -10^6 *W_L <= QS_L <= 10^6*W_L
        prob += QS_arr[s] >= -10**6*W_arr[s]
        prob += QS_arr[s] <= 10**6*W_arr[s]

        #constraint 8
        #prob += -10^6 *W_L <= PF_L <= 10^6*W_L
        prob += PF_arr[f] >= -10**6*W_arr[f]
        prob += PF_arr[f] <= 10**6*W_arr[f]

        #constraint 9
        #prob += -10^6 *W_L <= QF_L <= 10^6*W_L
        prob += QF_arr[f] >= -10**6*W_arr[f]
        prob += QF_arr[f] <= 10**6*W_arr[f]

        prob += W_arr[i] <= 1
        prob += W_arr[i] >= 0

        # #constraint 10
        # #prob += -10^6 *W_L <= PL_L <= 10^6*W_L
        # prob += PL[i] >= -10**6*W_arr[i]
        # prob += PL[i] <= 10**6*W_arr[i]

        # #constraint 11
        # #prob += -10^6 *W_L <= QL_L <= 10^6*W_L
        # prob += QL[i] >= -10**6*W_arr[i]
        # prob += QL[i] <= 10**6*W_arr[i]

    for i in range(1, number_of_buses):
        # # constraint 4
        # # GS_i is bus i conductance element
        # # PD_i is active load connected to bus i
        # # PG_i is active power generation connected to bus i
        # # prob += sum(PS for PS in PS_arr) + sum(PF for PF in PF_arr) - 1*GS[i] == PD[i] - PG[i]
        # prob += PS_sum + PF_sum - 1*GS[i] == PD[i] - PG[i]

        # # constraint 5
        # # BS_i is bus i susceptance element
        # # QD_i is reactive load connected to bus i
        # # QG_i is reactive power connected to bus i
        # # prob += sum(QS for QS in QS_arr) + sum(QF for QF in QF_arr) - 1*BS[i] == QD[i] - QG[i]
        # prob += QS_sum + QF_sum - 1*BS[i] == QD[i] - QG[i]
        F_index = [j for j, x in enumerate(FN) if x == i+1]
        S_index = [j for j, x in enumerate(SN) if x == i+1]
        if len(F_index) == 0 and len(S_index) == 0:
            pass
        elif len(F_index) == 0 and len(S_index) == 1:
            prob += PS_arr[S_index[0]] == PD[i] - PG[i]
            prob += QS_arr[S_index[0]] == QD[i] - QG[i]
            print(f"Bus {i+1}: {PS_arr[S_index[0]]}")
        elif len(F_index) == 0 and len(S_index) == 2:
            prob += PS_arr[S_index[0]] + PS_arr[S_index[1]] == PD[i] - PG[i]
            prob += QS_arr[S_index[0]] + QS_arr[S_index[1]] == QD[i] - QG[i]
            print(f"Bus {i+1}: {PS_arr[S_index[0]]} + {PS_arr[S_index[1]]}")
        elif len(F_index) == 1 and len(S_index) == 0:
            prob +=  PF_arr[F_index[0]] == PD[i] - PG[i]
            prob +=  QF_arr[F_index[0]] == QD[i] - QG[i]
            print(f"Bus {i+1}: {PF_arr[F_index[0]]}")
        elif len(F_index) == 1 and len(S_index) == 1:
            prob += PS_arr[S_index[0]] + PF_arr[F_index[0]] == PD[i] - PG[i]
            prob += QS_arr[S_index[0]] + QF_arr[F_index[0]] == QD[i] - QG[i]
            print(f"Bus {i+1}: {PS_arr[S_index[0]]} + {PF_arr[F_index[0]]}")
        elif len(F_index) == 1 and len(S_index) == 2:
            prob += PS_arr[S_index[0]] + PS_arr[S_index[1]] + PF_arr[F_index[0]] == PD[i] - PG[i]
            prob += QS_arr[S_index[0]] + QS_arr[S_index[1]] + QF_arr[F_index[0]] == QD[i] - QG[i]
            print(f"Bus {i+1}: {PS_arr[S_index[0]]} + {PS_arr[S_index[1]]} + {PF_arr[F_index[0]]}")
        elif len(F_index) == 2 and len(S_index) == 0:
            prob += PF_arr[F_index[0]] + PF_arr[F_index[1]] == PD[i] - PG[i]
            prob += QF_arr[F_index[0]] + QF_arr[F_index[1]] == QD[i] - QG[i]
            print(f"Bus {i+1}: {PF_arr[F_index[0]]} + {PF_arr[F_index[1]]}")
        elif len(F_index) == 2 and len(S_index) == 1:
            prob += PS_arr[S_index[0]] + PF_arr[F_index[0]] + PF_arr[F_index[1]] == PD[i] - PG[i]
            prob += QS_arr[S_index[0]] + QF_arr[F_index[0]] + QF_arr[F_index[1]] == QD[i] - QG[i]
            print(f"Bus {i+1}: {PS_arr[S_index[0]]} + {PF_arr[F_index[0]]} + {PF_arr[F_index[1]]}")
        elif len(F_index) == 2 and len(S_index) == 2:
            prob += PS_arr[S_index[0]] + PS_arr[S_index[1]] + PF_arr[F_index[0]] + PF_arr[F_index[1]] == PD[i] - PG[i]
            prob += QS_arr[S_index[0]] + QS_arr[S_index[1]] + QF_arr[F_index[0]] + QF_arr[F_index[1]] == QD[i] - QG[i]
            print(f"Bus {i+1}: {PS_arr[S_index[0]]} + {PS_arr[S_index[1]]} + {PF_arr[F_index[0]]} + {PF_arr[F_index[1]]}")
        else:
            print("Error: More than 3 line on sending or receiving side of bus")
        F_index.clear()
        S_index.clear()


        # print("Bus "+str(i+1)+":")
        # print("recieving: "+str(PS_sum)+", sending: "+str(PF_sum)+", demand: "+str(PD[i])+", generation: "+str(PG[i]))
        # print()

    # constraint 10
    # of closed lines = #of buses - #of slack buses
    prob+= sum(W for W in W_arr) == number_of_buses - number_of_substations


    ###############################################################################
    #                      END OF PROBLEM DECLARATION                             #
    ###############################################################################
    #write the problem to a file
    prob.writeLP('lpfiletest')

    solver = pulp.PULP_CBC_CMD()
    solver.actualSolve(prob)

    status = solver.readsol_LP
    # status = prob.solve(PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=1))
    # print(status)

    #show the values of the solved variables and the objective function solution
    print(value(prob.objective))
    minimum_losses = prob.objective.value()
    print(minimum_losses)
    print()
```

The solver returns an error and I am not sure where to go from here. Also to give some context the W_arr contains binary variables that defines whether a line is closed (1) or open (0)

I tried many things to get to this point but now I am stuck ( I am running Windows and python on Vscode)

**Here is the error message:**

Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver
Version: 2.10.3
Build Date: Dec 15 2019

(default strategy 1)
At line 2 NAME          MODEL
At line 3 ROWS
At line 588 COLUMNS
At line 2030 RHS
At line 2614 BOUNDS
At line 2800 ENDATA
Problem MODEL has 583 rows, 185 columns and 1293 elements
Coin0008I MODEL read with 0 errors
Option for timeMode changed from cpu to elapsed
Continuous objective value is 0.100508 - 0.01 seconds
Cgl0003I 0 fixed, 0 tightened bounds, 69 strengthened rows, 0 substitutions
Cgl0003I 0 fixed, 0 tightened bounds, 216 strengthened rows, 0 substitutions
Cgl0003I 0 fixed, 0 tightened bounds, 145 strengthened rows, 0 substitutions
Cgl0003I 0 fixed, 0 tightened bounds, 165 strengthened rows, 0 substitutions
Cgl0003I 0 fixed, 0 tightened bounds, 155 strengthened rows, 0 substitutions
Cgl0003I 0 fixed, 0 tightened bounds, 170 strengthened rows, 0 substitutions
Cgl0003I 0 fixed, 0 tightened bounds, 164 strengthened rows, 0 substitutions
Cgl0003I 0 fixed, 0 tightened bounds, 172 strengthened rows, 0 substitutions
Cgl0003I 0 fixed, 0 tightened bounds, 160 strengthened rows, 0 substitutions
Cgl0004I processed model has 409 rows, 111 columns (37 integer (37 of which binary)) and 1105 elements
Cbc0038I Initial state - 0 integers unsatisfied sum - 2.84504e-06
Cbc0038I Pass   1: suminf.    0.00000 (0) obj. 0.100508 iterations 41
Cbc0038I Pass   2: suminf.    0.00000 (0) obj. 0.100508 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass   3: suminf.    0.00000 (0) obj. 0.129584 iterations 25
Cbc0038I Pass   4: suminf.    0.00000 (0) obj. 0.129584 iterations 21
Cbc0038I Pass   5: suminf.    0.00000 (0) obj. 0.129584 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass   6: suminf.    0.00000 (0) obj. 0.135388 iterations 16
Cbc0038I Pass   7: suminf.    0.00000 (0) obj. 0.135388 iterations 6
Cbc0038I Pass   8: suminf.    0.00000 (0) obj. 0.135388 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass   9: suminf.    0.00000 (0) obj. 0.134919 iterations 32
Cbc0038I Pass  10: suminf.    0.00000 (0) obj. 0.134919 iterations 10
Cbc0038I Pass  11: suminf.    0.00000 (0) obj. 0.134919 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass  12: suminf.    0.00000 (0) obj. 0.136512 iterations 10
Cbc0038I Pass  13: suminf.    0.00000 (0) obj. 0.136512 iterations 4
Cbc0038I Pass  14: suminf.    0.00000 (0) obj. 0.136512 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass  15: suminf.    0.00000 (2) obj. 0.135955 iterations 21
Cbc0038I Pass  16: suminf.    0.00000 (0) obj. 0.135955 iterations 21
Cbc0038I Pass  17: suminf.    0.00000 (0) obj. 0.135955 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass  18: suminf.    0.00001 (2) obj. 0.141651 iterations 16
Cbc0038I Pass  19: suminf.    0.00000 (0) obj. 0.141651 iterations 11
Cbc0038I Pass  20: suminf.    0.00000 (0) obj. 0.141651 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass  21: suminf.    0.00001 (2) obj. 0.141651 iterations 6
Cbc0038I Pass  22: suminf.    0.00000 (2) obj. 0.140527 iterations 40
Cbc0038I Pass  23: suminf.    0.00000 (0) obj. 0.140527 iterations 11
Cbc0038I Pass  24: suminf.    0.00000 (0) obj. 0.140527 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass  25: suminf.    0.00001 (2) obj. 0.141962 iterations 20
Cbc0038I Pass  26: suminf.    0.00000 (0) obj. 0.141962 iterations 17
Cbc0038I Pass  27: suminf.    0.00000 (0) obj. 0.141962 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass  28: suminf.    0.00000 (2) obj. 0.142376 iterations 86
Cbc0038I Pass  29: suminf.    0.00000 (0) obj. 0.142376 iterations 13
Cbc0038I Pass  30: suminf.    0.00000 (0) obj. 0.142376 iterations 0
Cbc0038I No solution found this major pass
Cbc0038I Before mini branch and bound, 0 integers at bound fixed and 0 continuous
Cbc0038I Full problem 409 rows 111 columns, reduced to 409 rows 111 columns - too large
Cbc0038I Mini branch and bound did not improve solution (0.07 seconds)
Cbc0038I Full problem 410 rows 111 columns, reduced to 410 rows 111 columns - too large
Cbc0038I After 0.07 seconds - Feasibility pump exiting - took 0.03 seconds
Cbc0031I 17 added rows had average density of 2.9411765
Cbc0013I At root node, 17 cuts changed objective from 0.10050804 to 0.10050804 in 5 passes
Cbc0014I Cut generator 0 (Probing) - 21 row cuts average 2.9 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.002 seconds - new frequency is 1
Cbc0014I Cut generator 1 (Gomory) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.000 seconds - new frequency is -100
Cbc0014I Cut generator 2 (Knapsack) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.000 seconds - new frequency is -100
Cbc0014I Cut generator 3 (Clique) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.000 seconds - new frequency is -100
Cbc0014I Cut generator 4 (MixedIntegerRounding2) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.001 seconds - new frequency is -100
Cbc0014I Cut generator 5 (FlowCover) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.003 seconds - new frequency is -100
Cbc0010I After 0 nodes, 1 on tree, 1e+50 best solution, best possible 0.10050804 (0.09 seconds)
Cbc0001I Search completed - best objective 1e+50, took 444 iterations and 18 nodes (0.22 seconds)
Cbc0032I Strong branching done 138 times (157 iterations), fathomed 2 nodes and fixed 2 variables
Cbc0035I Maximum depth 3, 0 variables fixed on reduced cost
Cuts at root node changed objective from 0.100508 to 0.100508
Probing was tried 18 times and created 26 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.003 seconds)
Gomory was tried 5 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
Knapsack was tried 5 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
Clique was tried 5 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
MixedIntegerRounding2 was tried 5 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.001 seconds)
FlowCover was tried 5 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.003 seconds)
TwoMirCuts was tried 1 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
ZeroHalf was tried 1 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)

Result - Problem proven infeasible

No feasible solution found
Enumerated nodes:               18
Total iterations:               444
Time (CPU seconds):             0.23
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.23

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.24   (Wallclock seconds):       0.24

Comment: *The solver returns an error* Can you share the error message?

Comment: Hey Erwin, I updated the post to include the error message. Is there any other information you would need to help with this?

Comment: It looks like PuLP generates an invalid MPS file. Here is a good writeup on how to post a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: There are many duplicate rows. Unless you provide the data you're using, I doubt this will be reproducible.

Comment: Hello, I updated the post to include the LPFILE. I also fixed it to no longer have duplicate rows